# How to HTTP Post Request and Send Response from a Console Application in C#

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest

I have a Client And Server as follows.
On the Client Side,

```
HttpWebRequest toClient = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:10000");
            toClient.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            toClient.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
            toClient.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36";
            String DatatoClient = "ToAccountNumber=" + value.ToAccountNumber + "&Amount=" + value.Amount;
            toClient.Method = "POST";

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DatatoClient);
            toClient.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = toClient.GetRequestStream();

            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);


            //String DatatoProxy = "Account=" + 232303 + "&Amount=" + 200;

            //ProxySocket.Send(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toClient.ToString()));

            HttpWebResponse HttpResp = (HttpWebResponse)toClient.GetResponse();
            Stream respStream = HttpResp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(respStream, Encoding.UTF8);

            Console.WriteLine("Response stream received.");
            String receivedResp=readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

On the Server( Which is a Console Application in my Case) I have

```
bool recvRequest = true;
        string EOL = "\r\n";
        int bodylength = 0;
        string requestPayload = "";
        string requestTempLine = "";
        List<string> requestLines = new List<string>();
        byte[] requestBuffer = new byte[1];
        byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[1];
        requestLines.Clear();

        try
        {
            //State 0: Handle Request from Client
            while (recvRequest)
            {
                while (this.clientSocket.Available != 0)
                {
                    this.clientSocket.Receive(requestBuffer);
                    string fromByte = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(requestBuffer);
                    requestPayload += fromByte;
                    requestTempLine += fromByte;

                    if (requestTempLine.EndsWith(EOL))
                    {
                        requestLines.Add(requestTempLine.Trim());
                        requestTempLine = "";
                    }

                    if (requestPayload.Contains(EOL + EOL))
                    {
                        string[] list = requestLines.ToArray();
                        string body = "";
                        foreach (string s in list)
                        {
                            if (s.Contains("Content-Length"))
                            {
                                bodylength = Convert.ToInt32(s.Split(':')[1]);
                                for (int i = 0; i < bodylength; i++)
                                {
                                    this.clientSocket.Receive(requestBuffer);
                                    fromByte = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(requestBuffer);
                                    body += fromByte;
                                }
                                requestPayload += body;
                                requestLines.Add(body);

                                AccountNo = Convert.ToInt64(body.Split('&')[0].Split('=')[1]);
                                Amount = Convert.ToInt64(body.Split('&')[1].Split('=')[1]);
                            }
                        }
                        recvRequest = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Raw Request Received...as \n {0}",requestPayload);
            Console.WriteLine("Received the Account Number as = {0}", AccountNo);
            Console.WriteLine("Received the Amount as = {0}", Amount);
            Console.WriteLine("Server Received the above Details are they Correct ?\n Type 'Y' or 'Yes' for Yes and 'N' or 'No' for No.");
```

The above code is a Socket Handler. I am not sure If this is the right way o handle Http request in a console Application. What I am trying to do is to send a response t the received Http request as a http message with body as Yes or No from the console Application. The client will receive the response from this Console Application and pocess Accordingly.

I am not sure on how to return the Http response to client, Could someone point me if I am doing it right or Is it a better way to do it.

Thanks,

Comment: You need to create a RESTful Web service on your server.
Take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112470/Developing-a-REST-Web-Service-using-C-A-walkthroug) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you bother creating this server yourself from scratch? You can simply host a WCF service in your console app that exposes some bindings compatible with Http. It looks a much easier and cleaner solution

Here's an example from MSDN...

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Do you have any resource on how to do it? I am a newbie to C#. Thus I thought of handling this in Console Application and Sockets.

Comment: I've just added a link...